# Hibernate-search search by list of numbers

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I am working in a Hibernate-search, Java application with an entity which has a numeric field indexed:

```
@Field
@NumericField
private Long orgId;
```

I want to get the list of entities which match with a list of Long values for this property. I used the "simpleQueryString" because it allows to use "OR" logic with char | for several objective values. I have something like this:

```
queryBuilder.simpleQueryString().onField("orgId").matching("1|3|8").createQuery()
```

After run mi application I get:

**The specified query '+(orgId:1 orgId:3 orgId:8)' contains a string based sub query which targets the numeric encoded field(s) 'orgId'. Check your query or try limiting the targeted entities.**

So, Can some body tell me what is wrong with this code?, Is there other way to do what I need?.

=================================
UPDATE 1:

yrodiere' answer solves the issue, but I have another doubt, I want validate whether entities match other fields, I know I can use BooleanJuntion, but then I need mix "must" and "should" usages right?. i.e.:

```
BooleanJunction<?> bool = queryBuilder.bool();
for (Integer orgId: orgIds) {
   bool.should( queryBuilder.keyword().onField("orgId").matching(orgId).createQuery() );
}
bool.must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("name").matching("anyName").createQuery() );
```

Then, I am validating that the entities must match a "name" and also they match one of the given orgIds, Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says:

> The specified query [...] contains a string based sub query which targets the numeric encoded field(s) 'orgId'.

`simpleQueryString` can only be used to target text fields. Numeric fields are not supported.

If your string was generated programmatically, and you have a list of integers, this is what you'll need to do:

```
List<Integer> orgIds = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 8);

BooleanJunction<?> bool = queryBuilder.bool();
for (Integer orgId: orgIds) {
   bool.should( queryBuilder.keyword().onField("orgId").matching(orgId).createQuery() );
}
LuceneQuery query = bool.createQuery();
```

`query` will match documents whose `orgId` field contains `1`, `3` OR `8`.

See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_combining_queries

EDIT: If you need additional clauses, I'd recommend not mixing must and should in the same boolean junction, but nesting boolean junctions instead.

For example:

```
BooleanJunction<?> boolForOrgIds = queryBuilder.bool();
for (Integer orgId: orgIds) {
   boolForOrgIds.should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("orgId").matching(orgId).createQuery());
}


BooleanJunction<?> boolForWholeQuery = queryBuilder.bool();
boolForWholeQuery.must(boolForOrgIds.createQuery());
boolForWholeQuery.must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("name").matching("anyName").createQuery());
// and add as many "must" as you need
LuceneQuery query = boolForWholeQuery.createQuery();
```

Technically you *can* mix 'must' and 'should', but the effect won't be what you expect: 'should' clauses will become optional and will only raise the score of documents when they match. So, not what you need here.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue, Can you please check the update I posted?